# "В обратном(,) непривычном для нас порядке"

Tags: пунктуация

**Мне показалось интересным, если бы моя история начиналась с самого конца, т.е. была написана в обратном(,) непривычном для нас порядке.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужна. Между двумя определениями - пояснительные отношения. Причем пояснительные согласованные определения не выделяются, а лишь отделяются от поясняемого определения запятой. Т.е. перед словом *порядке* запятая не ставится.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна, конечно. Но правильно так: Мне **бы** показалось интересным, если бы моя история начиналась с самого   конца, т.е. была написана в обратном, непривычном для нас порядке.

Здесь тот самый случай, когда пресловутое "двойное бы" не только допустимо, но и необходимо по грамматике. И кабы не третье "бы" после "т.е. была [бы]".

Answer (score 0):

Запятая, конечно, нужна. Но как-то грамматика хромает. Какой вопрос можно задать к придаточной части?

Comment: Что именно хромает-то?

Comment: Показалось интересным (что?). Все в порядке.